# How to backup encrypted server without username&password

Tags: linux, centos

I was given a linux server to repurpose, but first of all, I want to back it up but I don't know username and password, and it may be encrypted. Now I am running this noisy server, there are only 4 items I can choose: Language, Session, Restart or Shut Down. Also, a field to enter user's info. Could you please tell me if this is possible, and if so then how?

Comment: SF isn't a site for asking homework questions. Please read the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not encrypted, you can attach the drive as a secondary drive to *another linux machine* and try running `dd` to duplicate the drive. Or, you could use `clonezilla` to duplicate the drive, technically this is bypassing security and I don't think I should be answering you, but in any event it will be useless to learn on *any computer* of which you don't have root access. Welcome to linux.

**Update**

If it is encrypted, then you're likely out of luck. You can try some basic default passwords for the root account which are googlable, but if this is truly just to learn linux then I suggest you blow it away and install linux from scratch, and use a book such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590599233) or it's [sequel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430216220) for a good primer. The former does give a brief intro to *nix commands on the bash shell, which probably doesn't mean much to you know but if you progress then it will.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR REPLYING!!! I guess it was encrypted, so you mean there is no way to do it?

Comment: @user2224373 please see my update, and don't forget to mark as answer if this helped you.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!
I found it was not so complicated. I entered single user mode, and changed the root's pwd, done. Now I am mounting an external hard drive, when I typed [yum search fuse] or [yum install fuse] on terminal, I only got [Loaded plugins fastestmirror    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile]. I am search for solution.